# Error building image due to pip version error

Tags: docker, ubuntu, machine-learning, pip, mlops

I am trying to build an image on docker for an app implementation, but when installing the requirements I stumbled upon an unmatched distributions error due to pip version 22.0.4. Even after running the suggested pip upgrade nothing changes and the version remains the same.

When I check my pip version it actually shows 23.0.1. Any idea why docker runs on pip 22.0.4 to build the image?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When executing a `docker build ...` command, the `RUN ...` statements are executing programs that are installed within the container. So while you have `pip` version 23.0.1 installed on your computer, the container you are creating has `pip` version 22.0.4 installed inside of it.

The `pip` version isn't your issue, as that line is only a `WARNING`. Your problem is with the requested `cloud-init==22.1.1`, as that line has the `ERROR` level. I don't see `cloud-init` in pypi and therefore I'm guessing you have the package name wrong.